# How to determine if the text file has a Unicode BOM or not?

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, byte-order-mark

How to detect BOM using Qt classes? What I'm trying to do is read a UTF-8 file, manipulate its contents and write it back. I can choose to either set or drop the BOM using `QTextStream`, but I don't see any way to preserve its original status (presence or absence) because I can't query it.

Comment: Would it be a political problem to declare the UTF-8 BOM a taboo and just never emit it?

Comment: @KerrekSB: It might be. I hate BOMs even more than the next guy, but this text file is used in at least 5 products - some of them written in C++, some in Delphi, others are Android and iOS apps. I don't want to mess with it and risk breaking something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `QTextCodec::codecForUtfText` to determine whether a byte array has a BOM:

```
QFile *file = ...;
bool hasByteOrderMark = QTextCodec::codecForUtfText(file->peek(4), nullptr) != nullptr;
// QTextCodec is owned by Qt - don't free
```

As a shortcut, you can exploit the (undocumented) fact that `QTextStream` will turn off `generateByteOrderMark` if it fails to detect the encoding from the stream:

```
QTextStream stream(file);
stream.setAutoDetectUnicode(true);
stream.setCodec(QTextCodec::codecForMib(106));    // default to UTF-8
stream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(true);

stream.readLine();    // detect codec and possibly switch off generateByteOrderMark

int mib = stream.codec()->mibEnum();    // detected codec, or UTF-8 (default set above)
bool hasByteOrderMark = stream.generateByteOrderMark();
```

This is undocumented behavior, so if you want to rely on it you might want to test.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: a UTF-16 BOM is 2 bytes (`0xFF 0xFE` for LE, `0xFE 0xFF` for BE), a UTF-8 BOM is 3 bytes (`0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`), and a UTF-32 BOM is 4 bytes (`0xFF 0xFE 0x00 0x00` for LE, `0x00 0x00 0xFE 0xFF` for BE).  So you need at least 4 bytes in order to differentiate between UTF-16LE and UTF-32LE (assuming you don't have a UTF-16LE encoded file with a null terminator immediately after its BOM).